# Trouble automating a dropdown menu in Selenium (Python) that takes me to another part of the browser. How can I do this?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I want to automate a drop-down menu using Selenium (Python). After clicking the drop-down, I want to click another option that will redirect me to another part of the browser.

I am having nightmares with this because everything I try goes wrong and it just looks so easy I don't know what I am getting wrong.

The dropdown from the menu is inside a script in javascript and inside this script there is a div.

In the picture there is the menu I want to access and then the option I want to click.

I would be very grateful if someone could help!!

Regards

I have tried several things, which include search using XPATH, id, class, CSS selector...Waiting for EC element to be clickable... Everything prompts time out exception.

The codes I tried:

```py
#1.Click in the dropdown "menu":
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[7]/div[1]'))).click() 

#2. Click in the dropdown option "project settings" 
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[7]/div[1]/div[10]'))).click()
```

Also I tried:

```py
#1.Execute JavaScript to click on the dropdown and open it
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_id("schedule_menu"))

#2.Execute JavaScript to click on the desired option
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_id("project_settings_single"))
```

I also tried with the select option but then realized it was not a typical select dropdown.

Comment: Please add the code snippets you tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AjeetVerma   Here they are:

Comment: #1. Click in the dropdown "menu"

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[7]/div[1]'))).click()



2. Click in the dropdown option "project settings"

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[7]/div[1]/div[10]'))).click()

Comment: please add the minimal-reproducible-example (that should include the URL or the Html snippet as well) to your post so that others can reproduce the error you're getting and give you the way to fix it